# C#. System.NullReferenceException thrown after running MSTest tests

Tags: c#, resharper, mstest, nullreferenceexception

I am using ReSharper tool to run my MSTest tests, but this exception is thrown:

> Test method ApiTest.Tests.RestCountriesTests.GetCountriesByCode threw
>   exception:  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.

**NOTE:** only tests with these annotations are failed:

```
        [TestMethod]
        [DeploymentItem("C:\\3.xlsx")]
        [DataSource("MyExcelDataSource2")]
```

But when I run them through *Test -> Run -> All tests* everything works fine and all tests work perfectly. But I need to make them work through ReSharper test runner, cause of HTML reports.

Comment: Make sure your tests are not dependent on each other.  Different runners execute tests in different orders.  So if one of your tests is dependent on a "side effect" of another test, you need to clean up that code!

Comment: @Caleb I am just practicing right now and these tests are very simple and are not connected with each other

Comment: Can you show example of a failing test?  The result output should also say what line threw the null ref.

Comment: @Caleb the problem is that tests don't fail when I run them through Visual Studio, and when I run them through ReSharper only tests that use DataSource fail

Comment: what are you doing in the tests?  what code in the test is actually throwing the null ref?

Comment: @Caleb taking parameters from Excel file and pass them to methods that send requests to REST API. as I said before, the same test works fine when I use Visual Studio to run it, or when I don't use DataSource and just pass parameters in the code

Answer (score 0):

Change Resharper settings to run each test in its own process space. Go to <kbd>ReSharper</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Unit Testing</kbd> and then check `"Use Separate AppDomain for each assembly with tests"`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, it was some problems with loading additional files (configs). I turned off 'Shadow-copy assemblies being tested' in <kbd>Resharper</kbd>><kbd>Options</kbd>><kbd>Unit Testing</kbd>, clean solutions and it helped me.